# Cypress doesn't run after upgradinig

Tags: cypress, upgrade

I had Cypress package version: 7.1.0.
I tried to upgrade version: 9.6.1.
Got following error and npx cypress open is giving error.
Need suggestion please.

---

PS C:\Users\MushfiquaZaman\OneDrive - BAFS\Documents\CypressTesting\Project1> npm install cypress@9.6.1

> cypress@9.6.1 postinstall C:\Users\MushfiquaZaman\OneDrive - BAFS\Documents\CypressTesting\Project1\node_modules\cypress
> node index.js --exec install

Installing Cypress (version: 9.6.1)

The Cypress App could not be downloaded.

Does your workplace require a proxy to be used to access the Internet? If so, you must configure the HTTP_PROXY environment variable before downloading Cypress. Read more: https://on.cypre
ss.io/proxy-configuration

Otherwise, please check network connectivity and try again:

---

URL: https://download.cypress.io/desktop/9.6.1?platform=win32&arch=x64
Error: unable to get local issuer certificate

---

Platform: win32-x64 (10.0.19043)
Cypress Version: 9.6.1
npm WARN Project1@1.0.0 No repository field.

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! cypress@9.6.1 postinstall: `node index.js --exec install`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the cypress@9.6.1 postinstall script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\MushfiquaZaman\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2022-05-13T19_11_23_404Z-debug.log
PS C:\Users\MushfiquaZaman\OneDrive - BAFS\Documents\CypressTesting\Project1>

Session contents restored from 5/13/2022 at 2:11:34 PM

Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

Try the new cross-platform PowerShell https://aka.ms/pscore6

Loading personal and system profiles took 1859ms.
PS C:\Users\MushfiquaZaman\OneDrive - BAFS\Documents\CypressTesting\Project1> npx cypress open
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:883
throw err;
^

Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\MushfiquaZaman\OneDrive - BAFS\Documents\CypressTesting\Project1\node_modules\cypress\bin\cypress'
at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:880:15)
at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:725:27)
at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:72:12)
at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47 {
code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
requireStack: []
}

Answer (score 2):

It's because you are installing into a "OneDrive" location which is a remote location to where your cache resides (hence the complaint about a workplace proxy).

Try installing to a local path and copying the project up to OneDrive, which I presume is what you did for v7.1.0.

Answer (score 0):

Please notice that log includes: "The Cypress App could not be downloaded.". Please download Cypress archive without using npm, unpack archive to cache ( C:\Users\your_username\AppData\Local\Cypress\Cache\9.6.1  ) then install it as previously: npm install cypress@9.6.1 .

Answer (score -1):

## Cypress.io Cannot be Installing Locally

#### Hello guys... I am facing the same issue. but now I have **Resolved it**.

[image: Screenshot_6]

### Here are the steps.

1. Create a Folder like "cypress-automation" Do not create only the "cypress" word. because it conflicts some time while installing.
2. Open a new Terminal in the Same Created "cypress-automation" Folder path
3. In the terminal Type the below Command and press Enter.

> npm init -y

4. After creating the package.json file Run the below Command and press Enter.

> npm install cypress --save-dev

5. It is Correctly Install Cypress.
6. No need to downgrade your npm version. Check your Node Version.

[image: Screenshot_7]

7. Go and check the Cypress document to which version you need to do the Cypress installation.

https://docs.cypress.io/guides/getting-started/installing-cypress

[image: Screenshot_4]

8. Install compatibility Node.js Package which is recommended in Cypress installation document Page..

https://nodejs.org/en/download

***---Happy Testing---***

Comment: This won't solve it, cypress does not work in Onedrive location.